# How do I drop an entire stack at once?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a way to drop an entire stack at once (instead of pressing <kbd>q</kbd> 64 times)?

Comment: You could hold Q down :P

Comment: Little is more fun than filming yourself doing the q method 64 times whilst making BLERGH noises over the top, then rewatching.

Comment: Just become a collector so you won't need to drop stuff.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As of version 1.4.6 you can now press Ctrl+Q to drop an entire stack at once

Comment: Changed answer due to new version.

Answer (score 36):

You can go to your inventory screen by pressing <kbd>E</kbd> (the new default key), click on the stack of items, move your mouse outside the inventory pop-up, and click.

---

(Mouse is where the floating stack of dirt on the left is.)
[image]

The result!
[image]

---

As Amazed stated, you can also simply close the inventory window while holding the stack of items.

Comment: You don't need to move the mouse outside of the inventory window. Just pick up the stack and close the inventory window.

Comment: Ahh, an even simpler solution. I'll edit that in, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Go to your inventory screen, click on it, and click outside the window.